# setting up VPN connection and accessing a remote windows computer

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn

I want to configure my Ubuntu to access a remote Windows machine from my Ubuntu.

I have to create a VPN connection and then only I can login and access.

I was able to configure it using the Windows, I created the VPN connection with correct credentials and then hit Win+R and put `mstc` and then It asked me the IP address of the remote machine and It gets connected.

I am not sure how can I get that thing settled in Ubuntu. This is very confusing question I am sure but someone might've had such situation.

Comment: it depends what VPN protocol you use, as far as I know IPSEC is one of few that are not available for Ubuntu sadly enough

Comment: I believe I am using that only. 

So that means I simply can not connect through my Ubuntu is what you are saying?

Comment: Basicly yes, I have been trying aswell but to no avail (itteraly what 4 months?)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the confirming. And there's no other way to do it either

Comment: using a VPN Specificly not that I know off (I never use vpns :P) if you want to remotely control your windows machine however there are multiple tools for that, like RPD, nomachine, teamviewer etc etc